window.open results in blank page after redirection
When I use window.open to open a site which redirects to my site, it results in only showing the background color of the body but without any visible content. The content loads but it's not visible until I resize the page.
<button>Click</button>

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('https://dashboard.palatial.cloud/project/663cdb4789db9b22c12cff23/share', '_blank');
});

But this code using <a> works fine:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'https://dashboard.palatial.cloud/project/663cdb4789db9b22c12cff23/share';
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.click();
});

What is the difference between both approaches? I'm not able to change how the user is being directed to my site, so what would be a way to fix this on my side?

@fdomn-m The window.open call uses _blank as well.

The _blank target is meaningless in the window.open call (or rather, redundant, and window.open will use a new blank window instance as the default target).

for <button>Click</button> the default type is type="submit" ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type

That explains the problem. But I'm not able to control how people are directed to my website so I can't change the button. Is there a way to make it so that I can handle edge cases like this from my side?

Re page submission, in the handler for the button click, add event as its first argument to pick up the click event object fired on the button. Then call event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation` to prevent submission of the page.

@traktor I can't control what the button does

If you can't change ... addEventListener('click', function() {   window.open... etc. , which doesn't change what  type the button is, what code do you have access to to implement a solution?

Just my website (which is the what URL in window.open redirects to)

When I use window.open - so you mean: when someone else uses window.open

It sounds like there's more going on here than is apparent for first reading; "to open a site which redirects to my site". What does this "site which redirects to my site" do? If it's doing something odd due to being called via window.open, you might have to counter that site's oddities, rather than the original site's use of window.open. I think some more debugging is in order; find out if there is something in your CSS that is responding to being opened via window.open; perhaps a particular window size?
